# How can I put JOptionPane in a specific point in the frame?

Tags: java, swing

How can I put this `showConfirmdDialog` in a specific point and not in the middle of the frame?

```
int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame,
                                             "Continue?",
                                             "Do you want to continue?",
                                             JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
if (choice == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
    break;
}
else {
    model.setRowCount(0); 
}
```

I tried with `setLocation()` but didn't manage to work.

Comment: If you want the `JOptionPane` to appear over a particular [JComponent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/jcomponent.html), simply replace `frame` with the relevant `JComponent` as the first parameter in call to `showConfirmDialog` method. If that's not what you want, then consider posting a [mcve] and stating where, exactly, you want the `JOptionPane` to appear.

Answer (score 0):

There is no parameter you can use to set JOptionPane location, but you can use parent component with specified location, for example JDialog:

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog();

dialog.setLocation(20, 50);

dialog.setVisible(true);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dialog, "Message", "Msg", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Unfortunately if parent component is not visible JOptionPane will appear in the center of the screen. Of course you can make JDialog object unvisible immediately after showing message dialog, but i think this code can not be named a clean code.

Comment: Or you could use method [createDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#createDialog-java.lang.String-) of class `JOptionPane`.